# Image inside li element does not appear

Tags: html, css

I am designing a menu to work with a responsive design website and I want to float a .gif image to the right of an li element.  The problem is that my .gif image does not appear after I try modifying my css.

HTML:

```
 <ul id="nav">
    <li class="first_item_drop"><a class="additional_item">Our Work</a></li>
    <li><a class="additional_item">About Us</a></li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.first_item_drop {border-top:1px solid #A9AFBC; background:url(../images/small_down_arrow.gif) no-repeat 10px right center;}
.additional_item {border-bottom:1px solid #A9AFBC;}
```

I've tried different approaches but I cannot get the .gif image to appear.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you put this in JSFIDDLE?

Comment: @JoshHarington Actually not near a computer right now, I can probably do this later tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.first_item_drop {border-top:1px solid #A9AFBC; background:url("../images/small_down_arrow.gif") center right / 10px no-repeat;}
.additional_item {border-bottom:1px solid #A9AFBC;}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mww43afu/)

Answer (score 1):

> [**CSS Backgrounds - 3.10. Backgrounds Shorthand: the ‘background’ property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background)
>
> `<bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box>`

Your syntax is invalid.

You need to specify the `background-position` (`right center`) *before* the `background-size` (`10px`). Both of which should be separated by a forward slash `/`.

Therefore, it should be:

```
background: url(../images/small_down_arrow.gif) right center / 10px no-repeat;
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/b1zjtj55/)